# Problem when adding 2 characters together

Tags: c

```
   char c = '2';
   char d = '3';
   char e = 'c' + 'd';
   int digit = e - '0'; // ACSII into int
   printf("digit = %d \n", digit); //should display 23
   printf("char c : %c \n",c); //should display 2
   printf("char d : %c \n",d); //should display 3
```

What I am trying to do is to is a string concatenation without using the strcat() function to display 23 as an int.
However I seem to be getting :

> digit = - 105

Comment: `char` is not a string, and using `+` does not perform concatenation. Nor does `'c'` perform an evaluation of the variable `c`.

Comment: `int digit = 10 * (c - '0') + (d - '0');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overflow! A `char` is just 8 bits long. By default, it's signed, so the range is `-128 <= x < 128`. You're adding the characters `'c'` and `'d'` (not the variables `c` and `d`) which means you're really adding the ASCII values, so `e` has the value `199`. Because it's signed, it's really `199 - 256 == -57`. Then you subtract `'0'`, which is `48` in ASCII, so you get `-57 - 48 = -105`.

Comment: This is a great answer! I'd add that to get "cd" you'd need an array of chars - you can't really concatenate in an abstracted way, in C.